# How to make a function so I can type what browser I want to open?

Tags: c++, windows, shellexecute

What is wrong with my code? I am trying to make a program where you can type what browser you want to open. VC++ keeps underlining equal sign in if statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void OpenBrowser(string browser) {
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", browser.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_MAXIMIZE);
}

int main() {
    char a;
    std::cout << "What is your favourite browser?\n" << std::endl;
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> a;

    if (a = "firefox") {
        OpenBrowser("firefox");
    }

    else {
        OpenBrowser("chrome");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is underlined because you are assigning "firefox" to variable **a** (since you have a single equals sing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main errors to note in the code.

1. Allocating variable `a` on the stack, please notice it's a char, meaning that you ask for a single (1) byte to be allocated on the stack (probably 4 because of alignment) to hold the variable that will be input. So for the variable to be able to hold a string like "firefox" or "chrome" we will need more data, for instace, `char a[MAX_PATH + 1];`
2. As been said, the `=` operator will assign a with *the pointer* to the "firefox" string, this will not work for two reasons, one being that the type `char` cannot hold a pointer due to it's size, the second reason being that the types are not the same (`char` - the input and `const char*` - "firefox").
   To add to that, if we would change the type of `a` to `const char*` changing `=` to `==` will not work either because in that case you are trying to check for equality between a pointer in your data section ("firefox") and a pointer to data on the stack (variable `a`), the `==` operator will simply check if the pointers are equaly, ie pointing to the same place in memory. So the easy way to solve this would be to use `strcmp`, [strcmp on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx).

**Tl;dr:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void OpenBrowser(string browser) {
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", browser.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_MAXIMIZE);
}

int main() {
    char a[MAX_PATH + 1];
    std::cout << "What is your favourite browser?\n" << std::endl;
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> a;

    if (!strcmp(a, "firefox")) {
        OpenBrowser("firefox");
    }

    else {
        OpenBrowser("chrome");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help. It worked out finally. I would never figure it out by myself!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how to open a browser using a user defined function and a call to [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void openBrowser(const std::wstring& browser)
{
    ShellExecute(0, NULL, browser.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
}
int main()
{
    openBrowser(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your comment was really useful. Thanks!